# How do I avoid losing my text area changes when using vimperator's external editor option with multiple tabs

Tags: vimperator

I use vimperator's external editor functionality via `ctrl -i` to edit text area fields with gvim.  This generally works, but I almost always use this with multiple tabs.  I find that I start editing the field with gvim, use another tab (say, to do a google search), go back to my gvim session, modify things, and write and quit the gvim session.  However, if I forget to open the original tab from which the gvim session was created before closing gvim, I lose my work. I then have to dig around in my temporary files to find the gvim file I lost.

Other than being careful to re-open the initial tab before closing the gvim session, is there a way to avoid this behavior?  For instance, is there a way for the quit gvim instance to write the content to the correct tab even if I don't have it open?

Comment: Isn't your question more suitable for superuser.com?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My solution to this is to use drop-in replacement addon for this feature called [It's All Text](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/its-all-text/)

It is basically standalone addon for this vimperator's feature that does this whole text-field tracking better in the background which allows you to use your browser while you have gvim or any other text editor open.

However it doesn't work for every field.